# NetLink Exporting Images doesn't work (Unknown string escape)

Tags: graphics, image, .netlink, file-transfer

Exporting Image files (intermittently) doesn't work:

[image]

I get messages back indicating the error is to do with escaping characters:

```
Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \\U.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question to help out other .Net/Mathematica developers in the future.

---

I am using random file names (DTWERG, ERYFGJ, IYIGGD) and it turns out when Mathematica exports an image file that has a slash and followed by : **b, t, n, f, r** it recognises/honors the escape slash.

For example when a file name starts with an **r** as per the screenshots, it treats the `\r` as a newline, a CRLF!

**Using forward slashes rather than backslashes resolved the problem:**

[image]

Comment: This applies to Windows-based filenames in standard *Mathematica* functions like `SetDirectory`. Hit that one today myself.

Comment: To be precise, `\r` is CR. LF is `\n`. Another way to deal with it is to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Put double slashes instead of single slashes:

Not:

> C:\Users\Blabla

Rather:

> C:\\Users\\Blabla